# How to check whether a date is any of the valid date types present in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The code below is validating only date types present in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and it should not contain time, but how to check a date field's validity in all the possible formats that SQL Server offers?

```
declare @dateofbirth varchar(max);
declare @dateofbirth_flag bit;
    if(ISDATE(@dateofbirth)=1 and @dateofbirth not like '%[:]%')
    begin
        set @dateofbirth_flag=1;
    end
    else
    begin 
        set @dateofbirth_flag=0;
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - if ever possible:

**You should avoid culture specific date/time literals and better use the appropriate data types!**

Your question has no plain answer for *all the possible formats that SQL Server offers*: A date `01/13/2016` is valid in a `mdy` culture, but is invalid, if the culture is `dmy`. Even more dangerous: If the date is `03/05/2016` it is valid, but you will get differing values from there...

In formats without a year like `03/05/08` you'll have pure chaos.

You might extract details with this

```
select * from sys.syslanguages
```

What I want to tell: You **have to know** and you **have to specify** the culture. Never rely on any implicit casting! Even a checked valid date might be a wrong input...

But you are in luck, since you are using SQL Server 2012. There is the new [TRY_PARSE and TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) where you can specifiy the target culture. You will get back a valid date/time or `NULL` if the cast fails.

On the linked page you'll also find `TRY_CONVERT` where you can specify a format via `style`...

Check this apporach with `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
declare @dateofbirth varchar(max)='12/13/2016';
declare @dateofbirth_flag bit;

SET @dateofbirth_flag=CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date,@dateofbirth,101) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
SELECT @dateofbirth_flag

--The result: `1` for style `101`    

SET @dateofbirth_flag=CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date,@dateofbirth,102) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
SELECT @dateofbirth_flag

--The result: `0` for style `102`
```

Comment: Thank you for such clear explanation ,Yes its right to specify the culture, but when i will import data from a deprecated excel file  i have to take care of all the possible date formats.

Comment: @SiddharthBhardwaj Okay, that can be a mess... One idea: If the dates are valid dates in the given Excel-Context you might use an Excel-Formula to generate a string literal in definit format...

Answer (score 1):

You can use try_convert function for your scenario like this,

In case of variable check

```
SELECT try_convert(DATE, @dateofbirth)
WHERE try_convert(DATE, @dateofbirth) IS NOT NULL
```

In case of table

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE try_convert(DATE, datecolumnname) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If there is the smallest chance to run an application in internation environment, you should never rely on the default culture, especially if the OP wants a solution for *all the possible formats that SQL Server offers*...